# Theos on mac error

Tags: macos, theos

I have done this (making hacks with theos before)
xcode 6.1
command line
coolstar theos
ldid
curl
perl
wget
make

However when I type

```
make package
```

I get these stuff

```
uname: illegal option -- o
usage: uname [-amnprsv]
```

But why "uname: illegal option -- o
    usage: uname [-amnprsv]" When it supposed to be s instead of o.
And how do I fix it?

Comment: Is there a Makefile? Then you can edit it accordingly. I would also file a bug with the developers.

Comment: Which makefile and where?

Comment: Have you tried searching for it?

Comment: I have many makefile on mac